# The best overloaded method match for 'Suprema.UFScannerManager.UFScannerManager(System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
    int nScannerNumber;
    ScannerManager = new UFScannerManager(this);
    ufs_res = ScannerManager.Init();
    nScannerNumber = ScannerManager.Scanners.Count;
    if (nScannerNumber != 0)
    {
        Scanner = ScannerManager.Scanners[0];
        Scanner.Timeout = 6000;
        Scanner.TemplateSize = MAX_TEMPLATE_SIZE;
        Scanner.DetectCore = false;

        byte[] Template = new byte[MAX_TEMPLATE_SIZE];
        int TemplateSize;
        int EnrollQuality;

        ufs_res = Scanner.ClearCaptureImageBuffer();
        ufs_res = Scanner.CaptureSingleImage();
        ufs_res = Scanner.Extract(Template, out TemplateSize, out EnrollQuality);                

        Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(500, 200);
        int Resolution1;
        Scanner.GetCaptureImageBuffer(out bitmap1, out Resolution1);

        imglefthumb.ImageUrl = bitmap1.ToString();                
        ufs_res = ScannerManager.Uninit();
        //btnStartR.Enabled = true;
```

> Blockquote
>   UFScannerManager(this);
>   Here I am Getting the errors are
>   "cannot convert from 'entry' to 'System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke"

"The best overloaded method match for 'Suprema.UFScannerManager.UFScannerManager(System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke)' has some invalid argument "

UFScannerManager.dll is

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Suprema
{
    public sealed class UFScannerManager
    {
        public UFScannerManager(ISynchronizeInvoke synInvoke);

        public UFScannerManager.ScannerList Scanners { get; }

        public event UFS_SCANNER_PROC ScannerEvent;

        public UFS_STATUS Init();
        public UFS_STATUS Uninit();
        public UFS_STATUS Update();

        public sealed class ScannerList
        {
            public ScannerList(UFScannerManager Owner);

            public int Count { get; }

            public UFScanner this[int Index] { get; }
            public UFScanner this[IntPtr ScannerHandle] { get; }
            public UFScanner this[string ScannerID] { get; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What parameter type is expected for the constructor, and what type are you passing to it?  Therein lies your answer.

Comment: @Seano666 Above is the dll

Comment: On this line, "ScannerManager = new UFScannerManager(this);", whatever this references needs to implement the interface ISynchronizeInvoke.

Comment: Will you describe me how to implement it. @Seano666